# Numba package not accessible through Jupyter NB

Tags: python, module, installation, jupyter-notebook

I installed the package `numba` using Anaconda Navigator 1.9.7 using Windows 10 and Anaconda2_2018.12-Windows-x86_64. Please note that I have Python 2 and 3 kernels within Juypter NB.

Here is the interface I used to install `numba`:

```
Environments base (root)
```

[image]

If I look for it by typing `pip list` on the Anaconda prompt, it seems like it should be there:

[image]

However, it is not accessible within Juypter NB (using a Python 3 kernel).

I don't know if the `0.41.0+0.gf11cda06.dirty` message implies that something went wrong with the installation.

Any leads as to the possible source of this problem?